# Lumen call to DB::connection() returns null even though select() is successful

Tags: php, lumen, lumen-5.3

I am using Lumen 5.3.1. `$app->withFacades()` and `$app->withEloquent()` have been uncommented in `app.php`. In `web.php` I run the following code:

```
$app->get('foo', function () {
    return app('db')->select("SELECT * FROM foo");

    return "Connected successfully to database " . DB::connection()->getDatabaseName();
});
```

The `select()` call correctly returns data from the `foo` table. However, `DB::connection()` returns:

```
FatalErrorException in Manager.php line 74: 
Call to a member function getConnection() on null
```

Why does one work but not the other?

Comment: Do you have multiple databases configured? Could you try DB::connection(_databasename_)->getDatabaseName() and see?

Comment: I only have one configured, using the .env file. When I made the change you suggested I get the same error.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'd say double check your service providers. It looks like you are going through [the DB Capsule](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/5.3/src/Illuminate/Database/Capsule/Manager.php#L74), when actually that's intended for use out of Laravel/Lumen. Anyway if you are in fact using the Capsule Manager, you probably have to register it in a `boot` method of the provider, not `register`.

Also, in order to find out more about what's going on, add this to your test code:

```
dd(app('db'), DB::getFacadeRoot());
```

Share the result if you want, this will give more information about the difference between the two methods.

Comment: The code did not recognize `getFacadeRoot()` from `DB`, so I used `Auth::getFacadeRoot()` instead. The result is a very long data dump. What information are you looking for?

Comment: `DB` is not a Facade then. Do `dd(DB::class)` then, and check the aliases and registered providers, in order to find out what "DB" is being bound to. Also, are you using any `use` statements?

Comment: The `use` statement was the issue. `use Illuminate\Database\Capsule\Manager as DB` gave me access to a `connection()` method but not the correct one. Removing the `use` statement solved the problem. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

```
 app('db')->select("SELECT * FROM foo");
 DB::connection()->getDatabaseName();
```

try

```
app('db')->connection()->getDatabaseName();
```

or

```
\DB::connection()->getDatabaseName();
```